# Rsync without creating hidden file in destination

Tags: rsync

rsync creates a temporary hidden file during a transfer, but the file is renamed when the transfer is complete. I would like to rsync files without creating a hidden file.

Comment: I haven't tried but i think `--inplace` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @alvits you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

alvits is correct, --inplace will fix this for you.  I found this when I had issues syncing music to my phone (mounted on ubuntu with jmtpfs).  I would get a string of errors renaming the temporary files to replace existing files.

Comment: strange.  i used --inplace and it still creates temporary files

Comment: had a issue with disk mounted with samba cifs. The filenames started with underscores and was getting bloked by samba as "noappledouble" because it was creating a ._XXX file.  Using --inplace in rsync fixed this.